# How to determine users connected ssh

Tags: ssh, users

I want to see how many users are connected to a PC to see who is gonna see the message when I do for example:

```
echo hello users! | wall
```

Comment: Do you only want to see `ssh` connected users?

Comment: Well, everyone who is gonna see the message when I do echo | wall , I guess they are ssh users

Comment: Sorry I am old school and used to have people connected via a tty and a serial line.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `who` command. It lists all logged-in users.

It's not just SSH users, it will also list users on the console and directly-connected terminals (if you have any). For SSH users, it will show where they're connected from.

Answer (score 6):

You want to run:

```
who -T | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2 | sort -u
```

Explanation:

- `who -T` shows all users and their writeable status ('+' -> you can write to them)
- `tr -s ' '` collapses multiple spaces in `who`'s output
- `cut -d ' ' -f 1-2` only take the first two fields (username + writeable status)
- `sort -u` sorts the list and shows only unique occurrences (in case someone is logged in multiple times, like often is the case for the console user)

That will give you something like:

```
anthon +
avanderneut +
franzi -
rae +
```

Answer (score 2):

`who` command will give you a simple info (user,  pseudoterminal, session start date, host ip) of the users logged in.

```
user    pts/0    2014-10-30 16:00:00 (1.1.1.1)
```

`w` command will give you a little more detailed info of the users.

```
USER     TTY      FROM     LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user     pts/0    1.1.1.1  16:17    0.00s  0.30s  0.02s sshd: user [priv]
```